# Adding MonadReader instance to a ReaderT wrapper

Tags: haskell

I'm just curious why this code doesn't compile. Why does it require m to be MonadReader ConnState?:

```
newtype Netbeans m a = Netbeans { unNetbeans :: ReaderT ConnState m a }
                            deriving (Monad, Functor, Applicative, MonadIO, MonadTrans)

instance Monad m => MonadReader ConnState (Netbeans m) where
    ask = Netbeans $ ask
    local f x = Netbeans $ mapReaderT (local f) (unNetbeans x)
```

The error message is the following(line 88 is line with local function definition):

```
src/Vim/Netbeans.hs:88:40:
Could not deduce (MonadReader ConnState m)
  arising from a use of `local'
from the context (Monad m)
  bound by the instance declaration at src/Vim/Netbeans.hs:86:10-54
Possible fix:
  add (MonadReader ConnState m) to the context of
    the type signature for
      local :: (ConnState -> ConnState) -> Netbeans m a -> Netbeans m a
    or the instance declaration
  or add an instance declaration for (MonadReader ConnState m)
In the first argument of `mapReaderT', namely `(local f)'
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `mapReaderT (local f) (unNetbeans x)'
In the expression: Netbeans $ mapReaderT (local f) (unNetbeans x)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you're applying `local f` to the base monad `m`, within the `ReaderT` transformer. Instead, it should look just like

```
local f x = Netbeans $ local f (unNetbeans x)
```

Comment: It looks like I overcomplicated things for no reason.